# How to show the selected index cell at middle of tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, tableview

I am doing one application, that i got `ten cells` for each row.

- And user can select the `index of cell` from list.
- By default `4 cells` are appear based on their height.
- If user selected index as 4 then we can show the cell at middle using `tableview` provided method.
- But if user select the `6th cell` then how we can show at middle of `tableview`.

How to do this?

Comment: Row itself is a cell.. How are you inserting cells in a row???

Answer (score 0):

You can selected a cell at certern IndexPath .Using :`selectRowAtIndexPath` with a param `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle`.

`[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];`

Comment: This will show selected cell at middle when that cell is in that 4 cells at that screen.But i need to show 6th cell which is not appear first and appear when we scroll